# Check if a record exists in App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

From what I've read, this is how I should check for any records...

```
    v = PC_Applications.all().filter('column =', value)
if not v:
    return False
```

But this returns an error!

> IndexError: The query returned fewer than 1 results

Any ideas to doing this? I've read that .count() is a bad option. I'm new to Python and App Engine so thank you for any patience!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if not v.get():
```

From [App Engine, Query Class get()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_get)

> Executes the query, then returns the
>   first result, or None if the query
>   returned no results.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
q = db.Query(PC_Applications, keys_only = True)
if not q.get():
    return false
```

I think `.all().filter('column =', value)` is even worse than `.count`, because it's not doing a keys-only query.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use the records, do something like:

```
results = PC_Applications.all().filter('column =', value).fetch(how_many_you_want)
if results:
    do_something_to_display_them()
else:
    do_something_else()
```